# Converted Pages in Books

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query all the books that have completed converting their pages.
A page is completed (converted) when the Text column is not null.

```
**Book**
Id
Name

**BookPage**
Id
BookId
PageNumber
Text
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a direct translation into SQL:

```
select * from Book as b
where not exists
 ( select * from BookPage as bp
   where b.Id = bp.BookId
     and bp.Text is null
 )
```